# Django cron runs multiple time, but it shouldn't

Tags: python, django, cron

I have multiple crons set in Django. In each CronJob I have set `ALLOW_PARALLEL_RUNS = False`. To run crons I have used linux `crontab` like follows :

```
*/1 * * * * /home/social/centralsystem/venv/bin/python3.6 /home/social/centralsystem/manage.py runcrons
```

After some times of running (for example after 2 monthes) I see lots of same crons running that make a lot of load on the server. My question is that what causes this happen?

one example of my cron classes is :

```
class UserTaskingCronJob(CronJobBase):
    ALLOW_PARALLEL_RUNS = False
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 5

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'user_tasking'

    def do(self):
        args = {
            'telegram': {
                'need_recrawl_threshold': 60 * 2,
                'count': 100,
            },
            'newsAgency': {
                'need_recrawl_threshold': 10,
                'count': 100,
            },
            'twitter': {
                'need_recrawl_threshold': 60 * 4,
                'count': 500
            },
        }
        for social_network in ['telegram', 'newsAgency', 'twitter']:
            user_queuing(
                SOCIAL_USERS_MODEL[social_network],
                social_network,
                args[social_network]['need_recrawl_threshold'],
                args[social_network]['count'],
            )
```

Comment: this cronjob is set to run at every minute, is this expected? what should be the time difference between the cronjob?

Comment: I have multiple crons in my Django project. one of them should be run every minute so I set linux crontab to run every minute. But for others `RUN_EVERY_MINS` is set to a large number.

Comment: The question isn't clear for what you're asking. You haven't given any example code to how the other crons are running or the code within `/home/social/centralsystem/manage.py runcron` Update your question

Comment: Hi Mohammed, you run your cron each minute, it may keep running more than one minute and cause more load on the server. please give me your runcron code to help more. in cron define the `*` and `*/1` are same.

Comment: `runcron` is a function of `django-cron` package. I have not wrote it by myself

Comment: ok, what is your cronJob class?, https://t.me/mrash14

Comment: I have editted my question

Comment: what does `user_queuing()` do? Is this a task that takes a long time? Note that if one of your tasks takes longer than 1 min to run, then django_cron won't have saved that task as being successful and will rerun it the next minute. Also since all jobs are run sequentially with the `runcron` command, if the total run takes longer than 1 minute, the tasks running at the end, after 1 minute has elapsed, will be rerun in the next minute and tasks will be duplicated.

Comment: how long time need to run user_queuing for each time? it may take more than one minutes to connect telegram, twitter and newsAgency and proccessing its content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful with django-cron, if you have lots of different tasks running for different periods of time. `runcrons` takes all your cron classes sequentially and runs them sequentially. It also only logs a cron (successful or not) to the database when it's done. I think django-cron could be improved by saving the cron log at the start already (and checking if there is already a running task), but that would still not exclude overlaps if multiple jobs are run rather than one long one.

You are running `runcrons` every minute, so in these cases you'll run into trouble:

- If during one of the runs, one of the tasks that needs to be run takes longer than 1 minute to run.
- If during one of the runs, the total duration of all tasks that need to be run takes longer than 1 minute to run.

In both cases, some tasks will not be logged in time to the database and while they are running, the next `runcrons` command will start them again.

To avoid this, do the following:

- Identify tasks that take longer than 1 minute to run and run them with a different schedule that ensures they have finished before the next run.
- In the crontab, run separate `runcrons` commands with a list of cron classes each, making sure that the total run of a list lasts less than 1 minute, e.g.

```
*/1 * * * * ./bin/python3.6 manage.py runcrons "my_app.crons.FirstCron" "my_app.crons.SecondCron"
*/1 * * * * ./bin/python3.6 manage.py runcrons "my_app.crons.ThirdCron"
*/10 * * * * ./bin/python3.6 manage.py runcrons "my_app.crons.LongCron"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I splitted crons on crontab and everything is solved

Answer (score 2):

Your cronjob is running every minute.

See [here](https://crontab.guru/#*/1_*_*_*_*) for an explanation

Crons are broken into:

`minute` `hour` `day(month)` `month` `day(week)`

The slash indicates the step value.

In your case, it will execute in steps of 1 minute. i.e every minute.

```
*/1 * * * *
```

Comment: I know that but this is what I want. One of my django crons should be run every minutes.

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate that you wanted it to run at a specified interval. You asked why is it running every minute. Update your question for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a lock file for each social network and check is your last collector finished. for example, make `/tmp/telegram.lock` at the start of your code (and stop the job if its exist) and remove it at the end of code. in each time you want to start a new job check is old lock exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

I post my final solution so anyone else can use it.

First of all you should know that because of `django-cron` bug you should not expect it to prevent parallel running of single `cron`. So to prevent parallel running first you should write a separate linux `crontab` for each of your crons.

Secondly you should use some kind of locking to prevent single crons to be run multiple times by crontab. I suggest using `flock`

Answer (score 0):

Django cron by default uses the cache to maintain state of which jobs are currently in progress, so that it doesn't execute a task more than once unless specified to run in parallel.

If you have cache setup in your Django app then you don't need to worry and split the command multiple time in `crontab`

For more you can check it [here](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron/issues/41)

Comment: Yeah, that's how the docs seem to suggest it works.  However, like the original poster, I find that it doesn't seem to work that way, and fires off multiple cronjob instances when earlier ones take longer than the specified interval.

I'm wondering if perhaps what's required is to set `ALLOW_PARALLEL_RUNS = True` for the locking mechanism to actually work?  This seems perverse, but not impossible.